# How to emulate post-mortem debugging mode in HSpec/Tasty

Tags: debugging, haskell, hspec, tasty, ghcid

Haskell debugger does [support post-mortem debugging](https://ghc-users-guide-chinese.readthedocs.io/zh_CN/master/ghci.html#ghci-debugger-exceptions) (setting breakpoints on raised exception).

So it should be possible to drop into debugger on testing failtures, as `pytest --pdb` [does it](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/failures.html#dropping-to-pdb-on-failures).

In principle you should load test runner in `ghci`/`ghcid` with exception breakpoints enabled, and somehow make test runner raise errors on test failure.

But I do not know how to do it in practice. Are there any known ways?